# How to configure ESLint to catch undeclared local variables

Tags: javascript, eslint, static-analysis

In the following code, I would like ESLint to give me a compile error for the undeclared variable `v1`.

Is there any such option available?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head> 
    <title>HTML Doctypes</title> 
    <script type="module">

    function f1() {
        v1=2//I want eslint to give me a 'compile-time' error for this line
    }
    if(performance.now == 12345){f1()}
    </script>
</head> 

<body> 
<p>HTML is easy to learn.</p> 
</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: You can use ESLint with this rule: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars

Comment: with [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) enabled this would produce an error at runtime (assuming no global variable exists with that name)

Comment: Note that without additional restrictions, e.g. strict mode to avoid `with` along with non-global (primarily restricting any algorithmical operations on the variable environment), knowing code beforehand (the example is a module, who knows what else is loaded?), or allowing false positives (error for being undeclared, although it is declared, just in some obfuscated way), this is simply impossible. However, such restrictions in reality often apply, in which case a simple lexical lookup suffices, and i bet there are more than a dozen tools for it (typescript, probably ESLint, ...)

Comment: @Turtlefight `type="module"` [automatically means strict-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Strict_mode_for_modules).

Comment: @ASDFGerte i totally missed the `type="module"`, thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza I think you meant no-undef instead of no-unused-vars.
Here's what works for me:
```
    ...
    <script type="module">

        /*eslint no-var: "error"*/
        /*eslint-env es6*/
        /* eslint-env browser*/
        /*eslint no-unused-vars: ["error", { "args": "all" }]*/
        /*eslint no-undef: "error"*/
       ...
```
Here's the output:
```    
    sohrab@sohrab-HP-Notebook:~/proj/test$ eslint --ext .html testUseStrict.html 
    
    /home/sohrab/proj/test/testUseStrict.html
    17:13  error  'v1' is not defined  no-undef
```

Comment: @VLAZ et al, please take the comment above and mark it as the accepted answer. I changed the description of the question to mention eslint.

Comment: I agree, now the question is answerable, when it ask for how to configure a particular tool. I have voted for reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ElAoutarHamza I think you meant no-undef instead of no-unused-vars. Here's what works for me:

```
... 
<script type="module"> 
/*eslint no-var: "error"*/ 
/*eslint-env es6*/ 
/*eslint-env browser*/ 
/*eslint no-unused-vars: ["error", { "args": "all" }]*/ 
/*eslint no-undef: "error"*/
...
```

Here's the output:

```
sohrab@sohrab-HP-Notebook:~/proj/test$ eslint --ext .html testUseStrict.html
/home/sohrab/proj/test/testUseStrict.html 17:13 error 'v1' is not defined no-undef
```